# Can I subclass annotations with @AliasFor?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, annotations

I have some annotation which I want to change: add or change default values. Annotation cannot be subclassed, but there is an annotation of [`@AliasFor][1]`. I tried to use it.

I got

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface BaseAnnotation {
    String target();

    boolean redirect) default false;

}
```

and I made

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface DerivedAnnotation {
    @AliasFor(annotation = BaseAnnotation.class, attribute = "target")
    String target() default "";
    
    @AliasFor(annotation = BaseAnnotation.class, attribute = "redirect")
    boolean redirect() default true;
}
```

i.e. I wanted to add default value for `target` parameter and change default value for `redirect` parameter.

Then I have applied my annotation

```
@GetMapping("/v1/...")
@DerivedAnnotation
public void myEndpoint(...) {
```

but it is failing with error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
> to read candidate component class: file [/...Controller.class]; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException:
> @AliasFor declaration on attribute 'redirect' in annotation
> [...DerivedAnnotation] declares an alias for attribute 'redirect' in
> annotation [...BaseAnnotation] which is not meta-present.

What is it and what can be done?